# How to set JQuery Mobile datebox popup at the center of window?

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using JQM datebox as following now:

```
<input name="startTime" id="startTime" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options={"mode": "datebox"}>
```

But the datebox doesn't pop up at the center of window.
How can I to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set datebox pop to the center of window in JQuery Mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605797/how-to-set-datebox-pop-to-the-center-of-window-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Need more details. How are you initializing the `datebox` in your code?

Comment: Found one issu, you have to wrap your options: `data-options='{"mode": "datebox"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the Position of the PopUp: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/popupPosition/

Example 1 (http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6swq0t0k/1/):

`<input name="startTime" id="startTime" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{ "mode": "datebox", "popupPosition": "window"}' />`

Example 2:

```
<input name="startTime" id="startTime" type="text" />
<script>
$("#startTime").datebox({
    mode: "datebox",
    popupPosition: "window"
});
</script>
```

This will force it to center in browser window. You can also center over another element by it's ID if you want.