# How to set datebox pop to the center of window in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using JQM `data-role="datebox"` as following:

```
<input name="startTime" id="startTime" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options={"mode": "datebox"}>
```

But it always pop up at the left side of window.
Is there any way to make it pop up to the center of window?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the option "popupPosition" to "window".

http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/api/popupPosition/

```
<input name="startTime" id="startTime" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"popupPosition": "window", "mode": "datebox"}'>
```

Comment: Can you give an example how to use it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

CSS may be the answer you seek. You can attach a style to this to position and format the datebox.

Like this for example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Or there are many more CSS examples on that website.